# How do I open a port (inbound) with Java?

Tags: java, port, router

Is it possible to open an inbound port with Java ?

If not, how do programs like uTorrent open inbound ports in my router ?
e.g. the following records have been added automatically by uTorrent:
uTorrent (TCP)  Yes TCP 24995   24995   24995   192.168.1.2
uTorrent (UDP)  Yes UDP 24995   24995   24995   192.168.1.2

How can I do something similar with Java ?

Comment: I believe this is totally doable if you are running a jar locally but not doable from say an applet due to the sandboxing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: @DanielWilliams Even if that applet has been signed (and trusted by the user) ?

Comment: Well it really depends on how you are running Java. Even a signed applet might not be allowed as the documentation says if it is access by javascript it will be sandboxed like normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly "doable" in Java. There are several ways to do it. I used Apache Mina for one of my projects.

http://mina.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) class.

Look at the constructor, it receives the port number, and then look at the `accept` method, which will block waiting for clients to connect.